# Can jquery detect that an e-mail was sent from client's mail?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is: my website's user completes a set of fields (not a form), then hits "send e-mail" (some fields are verified for completeness), then the user's e-mail platform is activated through "mailTo", the e-mail is pre-populated and all the user has to do is send it. Here is the problem: Is there any way to detect that the user actually sent the e-mail? Right now, after the e-mail is supposedly sent, a little div pops up asking the user if the e-mail was sent, which is fine by me, but, I think, not solid enough. I do not want to use any external, type of "mail sender" app, or .ajax, due to spam issues, want to keep the communication as simple as possible, and, knowing that there is no complete way to verify an e-mail, prefer to leave it up to the user. This is why I also require a phone number to verify their booking (it is a hotel's reservation website). Here is my code:

```
$("#btnDone").click(function(){
    
    //variables, for verification purposes (check input of "input type: hidden" fields - not in a form):
    var ctxx = "", ce = $("#yce").val().length, ct = $("#yct").val().length, cnl = $("#cnc").val().length;
    
    //verification functions return error = 1, if error:
    if(ce > 0){isEmail();} //contains basic regex
    else{isPhone();} //one or the other is required
    if(error==0){iscnp();} if(error==0){isyn();} if(error==0){if(ct > 0){iscnt();}}
        
        //if verifications OK:
    if(error==0){
            
            //variables to be included in e-mail:
            ynx = $("#yn").val(), cex = $("#yce").val(), ctx = $("#yct").val(), cnx = $("#cnt").val(),
            npx =   $("#cnp").val(), ncx = $("#cnc").val();
            
            //structuring, before populating e-mail variables:
            if(cnl > 0){npx = npx + ", " + ncx}
        ctxx = "Phone: " + ctx + " " + "(" + cnx + ")"; temp = "E-mail: " + cex;
                if(ce==0){temp = ctxx;}else{if(ct > 0){temp = temp + " - " + " " + ctxx;}}
                
                //e-mail variables:
        var esubject = encodeURIComponent("Subject: Reservation at (hotel name)");
            var ebody = encodeURIComponent("Number of persons: " + npx
                    + "\n\n" + iv + " - " + ov + "\n" + stay  + " " + noni + " total" + "\n" 
                + "Reservation Name: " + ynx + "\n" + temp + "\n\n" 
            + "Thank you, we will contact you shortly to confirm your booking..." + "\n" 
            + "Please add any notes and special requests below:" + "\n\n\n\n\n");
                //send e-mail:
        window.location.href = "mailto:myemail@mail.com?subject=" + esubject + "&body=" + ebody;
        //asking the user if the e-mail was sent:
        $("#text1").text("Did you send your reservation e-mail?"); $("#text2").text("");
    }
});
```

The issue is with that last line. Instead of asking the user if the e-mail was sent, can jquery detect if it was? In other words, if the user hit "send" on his mail platform? Or, if that e-mail message actually reached my server? If not (probably the case), how can the above be done with PHP?

Comment: `Is there any way to detect that the user actually sent the e-mail?`...no. none whatsoever. Javascript/jquery cannot see anything outside the page it's on, never mind outside the browser. If you want to make this more reliable, send the data to the server and have php trigger the email (there are billions of tutorials online about doing that...I highly recommend one which uses phpmailer rather than mail())

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Protip: never use `mailto:` it looks (and acts) entirely unprofessional.  It may have changed in recent years, but there was also an issue where the body part wouldn't get transferred/populated in certain email systems.

Comment: Another thought: if the email you want them to send is going to _your_ server then why not just send it over HTTP using a standard online form anyway? I'm not sure why an email would be useful at all in that situation.

Comment: ADyson yes, I tried a form at first, but isn't what I am doing pretty much the same thing? The e-mail is meant to ensure that there are no double-bookings. The potential guest sends the e-mail to my cell phone, I then check a spreadsheet, tick off the dates, and export the spreadsheet to a .txt file, which is sent to the server. The website then, using the .txt file,  blanks out the booked dates from the website's booking calendar. Yes, I like automation, but automation in a lot of cases results in double-bookings. So, I waste a little time and do it manually.

Comment: `isn't what I am doing pretty much the same thing`...no, really not. Because a) you can't guarantee the data will be delivered, and b) you then have to check an inbox and process the data yourself instead of it going into your database. And wow, that's super-manual.

Comment: A competent online booking system should be easily able to prevent double-bookings. A common solution to that, which you might have seen on websites, is to put a room on "hold" once the user initiates the booking process - so it's not booked, but it also doesn't show up for anyone else who searches availability while the user is thinking about their booking / filling in the form and/or arranging payment. I would bet there are free open-source solutions you can use/build on out there to save the hassle of building your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't detect this client-side (directly), with jQuery or anything else.

You *can* detect this server-side, by putting a unique identifier in the email (for instance, in the subject) and having your client-side code call your server-side code to check whether the email has been received by your mail server. (You may have to poll [or use a web socket or server-sent events, etc.], it'll usually take at least a second or two, sometimes longer.) *How* you do it is almost entirely dependent on the details of your server environment (and would be too broad a question).

Alternatively, you can send the information to your server directly from your script instead of involving the user's email system, as [ADyson pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77328892/can-jquery-detect-that-an-e-mail-was-sent-from-clients-mail/77328934#comment136325752_77328892). That would be a fairly standard way to do it. If you need to validate their email address, send them an email with a code in it they then quote back (via clicking a link or replying to the email).

Comment: Thank you all for your input, I will consider what you suggested - that phpmailer, I will definitely work on. As you may have guessed, I am no programmer, I just love doing it as a hobby, although it involves a LOT of hit and miss, and - since I will need a website for the studio hotel I am building right now, I decided to do it by myself, for myself. It is quite a mountain to climb, but I am doing it slowly, with your help!